# Can I redirect from a layout file to a controller? or?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently there is code in one of my layout views something like this.

```
<%- pending_items = items.pending.count
if pending_reviews > 0 -%>
    <div id="notice">
        <%= link_to("YOU HAVE #{pluralize(user_pending_items, 'PENDING ITEMS')}", user_item_path) %>
    </div>
<%- end -%>
```

I need to expand the code with a few more conditions and then if a certain condition is met redirect to another action. Here are a few questions:

1. if there is a certain condition met, could i redirect back to a controller from the layout file? i haven't found anything that works yet.
2. also, would it make more sense to run all these conditions in a controller? I tried placing it in my home_controller but the layout was not picking up the values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like code that should be moved to a controller.  If you do this for every page, you can move it to application controller, into a before filter ([about filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)).  Remember that controller should set instance variables (those with `@` at the beginning) if you wish to use them in view.

Comment: i added the filter to my application_controller. works like a charm. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend placing the logic in your controller or model.  You will have to use instance variables to pass values to your layout:

```
# in your controlller
@pending_items = Item.pending.count
if @pending_items > 0
  ...
  redirect_to ...
else
  ...
  redirect_to ...
end
```

The @pending_items instance variable will be accessible in your layout.